# How to combine matching records while summing a field?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2016

I am creating a report that displays records along with a dynamic path image. I would like to combine records that have the same size, and sum the amount of units. For example: If both records are 36x36 and have 2 units each, I would like to display one 36x36 record with a unit count of 4.

I have tried the group expert but that doesn't seem to combine them, only separate them by size with a unique header.

The report:
[image: Report]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were in the right path, but need to move the images to the group section. Try again like this:

1. Create a group by size.
2. Move the images from details section to the group header (or footer) section.
3. Create a summary field to sum up the units in the group footer section.
4. Actually, I understand you will need to move all from details section to group footer (or header) section.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that you needed to move the fields into the header/footer. Kind of weird actually.

Comment: Keep in mind that the details section is designed to show each row, then it will start to make sense. The group expert will group the rows, what in practice means reorder the rows and group them together, but each row will still show up in the details section.